# How to publish array of images in Next.js 13 component?

Tags: image, import, local, next.js13, src

I cannot use array of images because only import of an image work, but adding src to Image doesnt work. My next js version "13.4.19". I think it maybe because of my nextConfig:

const nextConfig = {
experimental: {
serverActions: true,
},
};
But empty nextConfig didn't helped with images issue.

This code works:
import nextImg from '../public/next.svg';
<Image src={nextImg} alt={'logo.text'} width={32} /> works

This code doen't:
<Image src={'./next.svg'} alt={'Next text'} height={32} width={32} /> doesn't work

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Error 404 not found